# Array not being seen in scope Im not sure why SwiftUI

Tags: arrays, swift, swiftui

Code:

```
extension Array {
    // Total Together An Array
    func FindTotal(_ arrayName: [Int]) -> Int {
        var currentValue: Int = 0
        for i in 0...Int(arrayName.count - 1) {
            currentValue = currentValue + Int(arrayName[i])
        }
        return currentValue
    }
    
    // Number Grabber for Calculating the values
    func calcItemsD(_ TargetArray: [String]) {
        var placeholder: String? = nil
        for i in 0...Int(TargetArray.count - 1)  {
            placeholder = String((TargetArray[i]).character(at: 0)!)
            if (placeholder == "1") {
                dealerNums.append("")
            }
        }
    }
}

class DeckSetup :  ObservableObject {
    @Published public var deckOCards: [String] = []
    @Published public var yourhand: [String] = []
    @Published public var dealerHand: [String] = []
    @Published public var dealerNums: [Int] = [7, 2]
    @Published public var playerNums: [Int] = []
}
```

The dealerNums.append("") is throwing the error of out of scope and I am not sure why Heres the all the code that should be relevant.

Comment: You can use the built in function  `reduce` instead of FindTotal and calcItemsD should be moved to `DeckSetup`

Answer (score 1):

`dealerNums` is an array encapsulated in your `DeckSetup` class. You can't access that from an `Array` extension.

What you can do, is pass in `dealerNums` into the function, like so:

```
func calcItemsD(_ targetArray: [String], dealerNums: inout [Int]) {
    var placeholder: String? = nil
    for i in 0 ..< targetArray.count  {
        placeholder = String(targetArray[i].first!)
        if placeholder == "1" {
            dealerNums.append("")
        }
    }
}
```

And called like so from **inside** your `DeckSetup` class:

```
calcItemsD(["1", "K", "A"], dealerNums: &dealerNums)
```

`dealerNums` is marked `inout`, since you are mutating it within the function.

---

I cleaned up the function a tiny bit, but I don't know if you have more to it. For example, these are more things you could change to improve it:

- Iterate with `for target in targetArray` instead of using the index.
- `placeholder` is not needed to be stored outside the loop as it isn't used. You can have a local `let placeholder = ...` if needed.
- Don't force unwrap (`!`) the first character. Provide a suitable alternative or fallback.